# Azure Data Explorer Change Data Capture for tables & materialized view

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I'm looking to implement a scenario where the aggregates materialized in ADX can be used for further downstream processing in a streaming fashion instead of having query periodically (e.g., Az Functions listening to these aggregates in EventHub, and then triggering certain actions).

Does ADX support change feed be available on top of Materialized View, so that newly calculated aggregates are available in the configured Event Hub for stream processing ?

Comment: Please provide a full description of your scenario

Comment: Edited the question adding details on the scenario

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an [xyproblem](https://xyproblem.info/)

What would be the added value of putting ADX in the middle of a streaming architecture?
Why not working directly against what's feeding ADX?

If you insist on using ADX for this, you could use:

- [update policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/updatepolicy) to capture changes in a source table
- [continuous data export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-export/continuous-data-export) to spill the data to blobs

  - Doesn't support stream ingestion
  - Minimum interval of 1 minute
- [Event grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-blob-storage?tabs=event-grid-event-schema) to listen to new files creation

Comment: I tried using Azure streaming analytics, but with the event stream being irregular (out of order, late arrival of message even up to weeks - given there could be corrections posted even after weeks of original events), calculating aggregates in the stream doesn't yield correct results (with reasonable watermark configuration), and incorrect aggregates was not acceptable.

Comment: In other words, this is not a streaming scenario. My answer is still valid.

Comment: I was wondering if the aggregates materialized in ADX can be made available in EventHub. Looks like the answer is No, thanks!

Comment: And if you could, then what? you still need to pull them and do some manipulation on them and/or push them to another data system - and you're back to where you started.

Comment: Obviously not, i'd be able to use the aggregated event and then execute an action (e.g., calling a backend api using Az function) based on that.

Anyways, the question was about ADX capability, and not guidance on overall solution architecture.

Comment: No, you won't. You said that "there could be corrections posted even after weeks" and that "incorrect aggregates was not acceptable". That means that you cannot response no anything. It's not streaming. Only when a grace period has passed then you can act upon the aggregation. Nothing triggers it.